# How to interpret $\langle v, w\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \overline{w_i}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

It says $\langle v, w\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \overline{w_i}$ and the vectors $v$ and $w$ are in $\mathbb{C}^n$

As an example, suppose $v$ and $w$ are in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and are given explicitly by:

$v = (2, 1-i)$ and $w = (i, 4+3i)$

Then $\langle v, w\rangle = (2, 1-i) \cdot \overline{(i, 4+3i)} = (2, 1-i) \cdot (-i, 4-3i)$

In other words, the overline means take the conjugate of each component of the second vector?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Also note that $$\langle v, v \rangle =\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \bar{v_i}=\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2 $$